# Parameter 'array' implicitly has 'any' type. What does this mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

```
var milkResponses: string[] = ["I like milk", "mmmm"];
function randomArrayShuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
  }
```

What I want to do is randomize a string array such as milkResponses, but the array parameter has an error saying that Parameter 'array' implicitly has an 'any' type. I'm not sure what it means. I think its because I made the array wrong?

Appreciate the help

Comment: It means you didn't declare the type of the argument `array`.

Comment: Ie, change it to: `function randomArrayShuffle(array: string[]) {`

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing that either explicitly sets the type of something in TypeScript, or a reliable way for TypeScript to infer that type (e.g. by creating a variable and immediately setting it to a value), then TypeScript will implicitly give it the type `any`. By default, TypeScript is configured to not allow code containing any implicit `any` to compile, which is why you're seeing this error.

Because it's a function argument without a default value, you'll want to specify its value explicitly. It looks like your function can operate on arrays that contain anything, so you probably want to use `function randomArrayShuffle(array: any[]) {`